# Magento 2: How to add product QTY in layered navigation filter?

Tags: magento2.3, layered-navigation, filter, qty, filtered-nav

I need to add qty filter in Layered Navigation so Customer can filter products using qty.

**I have implemented using product stock status but due to backorders. I need to display products based on actual QTY.**

I have tried with using `"Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer"` Plugin but It's not work for product qty.

**Help will be appreciated.**

Thank you in Advanced